# drawText invisibile in android 4.4

Tags: android, android-view, android-bitmap

code fragments:the method getBitmap is to draw a bitmap which drawText() on it

```
public void showImageView() {
     imageView.setBitmap(getBitmap("something", getActivity()));
}


public static Bitmap getBitmap(String content, Context context) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.kfunsdk_stamp_bg)
            .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444, true);
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int typeSize = (int) (height / 1.7);
    int left = (int) ((width - typeSize * content.length()) / 1.8);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(typeSize);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    canvas.save();

    int top = (int) ((height - typeSize) / 2.5) + typeSize;

    canvas.drawText(content, left, top, paint);

    canvas.restore();
    return bitmap;
}
```

This is in android 4.4 result.

[image]

use same code run in android 4.3 reuslt

[image]

Comment: try with `paint.setStrokeWidth(4);`

Comment: I've tried still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing Bitmap configuration with 
`Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`